# Saving data into an hdf5 file: necessary to create a new dataspace for every dataset?

Tags: c, hdf5

I have a 2D array which I need to write into an hdf5 file. I need the 2D array split up into a set of 1D arrays, i.e. every 1D array has the same size. For some reason I create a new **dataspace** in my `C` code for every one of those 1D arrays. To be more precise, my current approach is

1. Open (or create) file with `H5Fcreate`
2. Create group with `H5Gcreate2`
3. Create dataspace with `H5Screate_simple`
4. Create dataset with `H5Dcreate`
5. Write 1D array into dataset with `H5Dwrite`
6. Close dataset identifier with `H5Dclose`
7. Close dataspace identifier with `H5Sclose`
8. Go back to 3. and continue with the next 1D array

After having a look at the [documentation](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5D.html#Dataset-Create2) for `H5Dcreate2`, I realize that I might not need to close the dataspace after each 1D array and create a new one afterwards for the next 1D array, as those 1D arrays are all of the same size.

My question: is there any reason, why I should create a new/separate dataspace for every single 1D array, if all those 1D arrays have the same size (but different content)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct: there is no need to create a new/separate dataspace for every single 1D array you create (in other words, just re-use the same dataspace as many times needed as long as all these arrays are of the same size and data type).

This is what happens when using [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com). Coding your algorithm above using HDFql looks as follows in C:

```
// declare variable
char script[100];

// create an HDF5 file named 'test.h5' and use it (i.e. open it)
hdfql_execute("create and use file test.h5");

// create an HDF5 group named 'my_group'
hdfql_execute("create group my_group");

// create 100 arrays
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    // prepare script to create a one dimensional (size 10) dataset of data type int
    sprintf(script, "create dataset my_group/my_dataset_%d as int(10)", i);

    // execute script
    hdfql_execute(script);
}

// close file
hdfql_execute("close file");
```

In this code above this is done transparently (from the user point-of-view) but this is what is happening under the hood.